# C# webdriver - how do I discover an xpath from a known element classname?

Tags: c#, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a website that has an "account" page that displays a table of available subscription levels, where the column headings are the different kinds of accounts, and the rows list all features, and which are available at what level. E.g.:

```
          fanboy       poweruser     neophyte     freeloader
Widgets   1,000        500           250          100
Doodads     750        350           100          100
Thingies    500        250           100           50
          [UPGRADE]    [UPGRADE]     [UPGRADE]    Your Plan
```

This is all done as nested `div` elements with unique classnames, so finding specific cells by their corresponding classnames is a snap. E.g.:

```
var yourPlan = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("your_plan"));
```

I can also find specific cells by their XPath, if I already know it. E.g.:

```
var yourPlan = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='your_plan']"));
```

But there are times when I need to discover the xpath of the cell I've come to by way of classname, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this in Webdriver (C#). Has anyone done this before?

---

**EDIT:** Apologies to all, for not being clearer about this: I'm not having any trouble finding an element by classname or other attribute (or even xpath, when I know it already). But what I need, is a way for webdriver to report the full xpath of what it found to me, once it's found said element via a means other than xpath.

Hope that helps.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Greg

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe that XmlElement (and/or XmlNode) instances would know their Parent, so you should be able to write a straightforward routine to walk back to the root and construct their xpath (I'm assuming C# from the tag).  After finding the parent it would need to scan the children of that parent until it finds the node it was in while counting the number of preceeding sibling nodes with the same element name in order to include indexing (eg. "[2]") when needed.

Comment: Interesting idea. Webdriver does provide the raw html via PageSource, so maybe I could feed that into a C# xml object.

Comment: Oh, BTW, it can require some extensive cleanup of HTML to make it parsable XML. I recently worked on a project where code to perform that cleanup was already done and I was forgetting that it was necessary before loading it into an XmlDocument object (unless what you're working with already does that; I'm not familiar with selenium). In your case, it may be easier to write your own simple context scanner to keep track of the effective current Xpath as it scans the HTML until it reaches the desired spot (assuming you can identify it from what you already know).  Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any way for Selenium to give you this information. While there are some tools that will generate the XPath for a given element (the Firebug and XPather plug-ins for Firefox come to mind), this is not a feature that Selenium provides. I wish I had a better answer for you, but the answer is no, Selenium won't provide you with the XPath to an element that you've found via some other means.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I appreciate the response. I'm going to try to cobble something together using PageSource as an input to a C# XML object, where the options are limitless :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create the XPath expression string with something like:

```
"//div[@class='" + className + "']"
```

If the classnames are indeed unique, this XPath expression will find only that div. If you don't know whether the element is a div or something else, use

```
"//*[@class='" + className + "']"
```